# problems with kernel not being loaded

Tags: gcc, makefile, gnu-make, osdev

I'm creating an OS and when I compile the code nothing happened, simply nothing(No errors, warnings or anything) I"m thinking that the make file has some issues.

Makefile:

```
build_kernel:
    echo "Building kernel..."
    ${ASM} ./src/kernel/kernel_entry.asm -f elf64 -o ${BUILD_DIR}/kernel_entry.o
    ${C_COMPILER} -c ./src/kernel/kernel.c -o ${BUILD_DIR}/kernel_start.o
    ${C_COMPILER} -c ./src/kernel/drivers/printutils.c -o ${BUILD_DIR}/kernel_printutils.o
    ${C_COMPILER} -c ./src/kernel/drivers/port.c -o ${BUILD_DIR}/kernel_ports.o
    echo "kernel build complete."

link:
    echo "Linking..."
    ${LINKER} -o ${BUILD_DIR}/kernel.bin ${BUILD_DIR}/kernel_ports.o \
        ${BUILD_DIR}/kernel_printutils.o ${BUILD_DIR}/kernel_start.o \
        ${BUILD_DIR}/kernel_entry.o -Ttext 0x1000 --oformat binary
    echo "Linking complete"

run:
    echo "Running qemu..."
    qemu-system-x86_64 -fda ${BUILD_DIR}/os.bin

merge_binary:
    echo "Merging binary..."
    cat ${BUILD_DIR}/boot.bin ${BUILD_DIR}/kernel.bin > ${BUILD_DIR}/os.bin
    echo "Binary merged."

post_build:
    rm -f ${BUILD_DIR}/boot.bin
    rm -f ${BUILD_DIR}/kernel.bin
    rm -f ${BUILD_DIR}/kernel.o
    rm -f ${BUILD_DIR}/kernel_entry.o
    rm -f ${BUILD_DIR}/kernel_ports.o
    rm -f ${BUILD_DIR}/kernel_printutils.o
    rm -f ${BUILD_DIR}/kernel_start.o
```

I'm wondering what is happening with the makefile and is this the correct way to compile all the code into object files and link them.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is that the complete `makefile`?  How do you invoke `make`?

Comment: None of your targets lists any dependencies after the colon `:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just commenting on your make style -- this does not answer why you are outputting nothing (and it is unclear what you mean by that -- if you run `make`, it should output at least `echo "Building kernel..."`...).   As far as the makefile style goes, this seems to be built using a scripting mentality rather than a make mentality.   Consider your first part:

```
build_kernel:
    echo "Building kernel..."
    ${ASM} ./src/kernel/kernel_entry.asm -f elf64 -o ${BUILD_DIR}/kernel_entry.o
    ${C_COMPILER} -c ./src/kernel/kernel.c -o ${BUILD_DIR}/kernel_start.o
    ${C_COMPILER} -c ./src/kernel/drivers/printutils.c -o ${BUILD_DIR}/kernel_printutils.o
    ${C_COMPILER} -c ./src/kernel/drivers/port.c -o ${BUILD_DIR}/kernel_ports.o
    echo "kernel build complete."
```

This has several issues.   First is the name -- this looks to build a bunch of artifacts rather than building the kernel.   Also, the recipe never produces a file named `build_kernel`, thus this should have been a phony target.   Next, this is actually a script, which builds four separate things.   These could be separated out into four separate rules, each which builds one thing, and then the main target would be dependent on this.   Thus, it might look like:

```
.PHONY: build_kernel_objs
build_kernel_objs: ${C_OBJS} ${ASM_OBJS}
  @echo done building $@

${BUILD_DIR}/kernel_start.o : ./src/kernel/kernel.c
  ${C_COMPILER} -c $< -o $@

${BUILD_DIR}/kernel_printutils.o : ./src/kernel/kernel_printutils.c
  ${C_COMPILER} -c $< -o $@

${BUILD_DIR}/kernel_ports.o : ./src/kernel/kernel_ports.c
  ${C_COMPILER} -c $< -o $@
```

Note that the above is repetitive, and if you have hundreds of files, will bolat very quickly.  This can also be done using [static pattern](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Pattern.html) rules:

```
C_FILES := \
  ./src/kernel/kernel_start.c
  ./src/kernel/kernel_printutils.c
  ./src/kernel/kernel_ports.c

ASM_FILES := \
  ./src/kernel/kernel_entry.asm

C_OBJS := ${C_FILES :./src/kernel/%.c=${BUILD_DIR}/%.o}
ASM_OBJS := ${ASM_FILES :./src/kernel/%.asm=${BUILD_DIR}/%.o}

${C_OBJS} : ${BUILD_DIR}/%.o : ./src/kernel/%.c
  ${C_COMPILER} -c $< $@

.PHONY: build_kernel_objs

build_kernel_objs: ${C_OBJS} ${ASM_OBJS}
  @echo "done building $@"
```

These have several advantages over what you've done -- first, make will only ever build the objects that are out of date, so it doesn't do needless work.   It can also build the files in parallel if a `-j` option is specified on the make command line.  Next, it's more maintainable -- if you have to add extra files, you can do it in one place, and everything works out.   Also, the `.PHONY` prevents the make from failing if you happen to have a file named `build_kernel_objs` in your make directory.  Lastly, the `@` in front of the `echo` lines prevents the actual echo command from being echoed, which will look nicer.

On caveat to this is that it does not handle modification of header files (as written, if a header file is updated, c files that depend on it would not be rebuilt.   See [here](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/) for some notes about getting around that.

The next section, `link`, the makefile recipe should reflect the target.

```
.PHONY: link
link : ${BUILD_DIR}/kernel.bin

${BUILD_DIR}/kernel.bin: ${C_OBJS} ${ASM_OBJS}
    ${LINKER} -o $@ $^ -Ttext 0x1000 --oformat binary
```

This creates a phony target link, so you can type `make link`.   It will only do the link if any of the C objects or ASM objects have been updated.   The same concept applies to your `merge_binary` target

For `run`, this seems to be somewhat contentious, but a common rule of thumb is that a `make` should be used to *make* an executable, not to run it.   A separate shell script is better suited if you want to invoke your built target with specific parameters.

Lastly, your `post_build` rule should likely be renamed to `CLEAN`, and declared as a phony.